# iOS Swift: Array Grouping of Double variables

Tags: swift, dictionary, grouping

I have an array of `Double` type.

```
[0,0.066666666666666666,0.13333333333333333,0.20000000000000001,0.26666666666666666,0.33333333333333331,0.40000000000000002,0.46666666666666667,0.53333333333333333,0.59999999999999998,0.66666666666666663,0.73333333333333328,0.80000000000000004,0.8666666666666667,0.93333333333333335,1,1.0666666666666667,1.1333333333333333,1.2,1.2666666666666666,1.3333333333333333,1.3999999999999999,1.4666666666666666,1.5333333333333334,1.6000000000000001,1.6666666666666667,1.7333333333333334,1.8,1.8666666666666667,1.9333333333333333,2,2.0666666666666669,2.1333333333333333,2.2000000000000002,2.2666666666666666,2.3333333333333335,2.3999999999999999,2.4666666666666668,2.5333333333333332,2.6000000000000001,2.6666666666666665,2.7333333333333334,2.7999999999999998,2.8666666666666667,2.9333333333333331,3,3.0666666666666669,3.1333333333333333,3.2000000000000002,3.2666666666666666,3.3333333333333335,3.3999999999999999,3.4666666666666668,3.5333333333333332,3.6000000000000001,3.6666666666666665,3.7333333333333334,3.7999999999999998,3.8666666666666667,3.9333333333333331,4,4.0666666666666664,4.1333333333333337,4.2000000000000002,4.2666666666666666,4.333333333333333,4.4000000000000004,4.4666666666666668,4.5333333333333332,4.5999999999999996,4.666666666666667,4.7333333333333334,4.7999999999999998,4.8666666666666663,4.9333333333333336,5,5.0666666666666664,5.1333333333333337,5.2000000000000002,5.2666666666666666,5.333333333333333,5.4000000000000004,5.4666666666666668,5.5333333333333332,5.5999999999999996,5.666666666666667,5.7333333333333334,5.7999999999999998,5.8666666666666663,5.9333333333333336,6,6.0666666666666664,6.1333333333333337,6.2000000000000002,6.2666666666666666,6.333333333333333,6.4000000000000004,6.4666666666666668,6.5333333333333332,6.5999999999999996,6.666666666666667,6.7333333333333334,6.7999999999999998,6.8666666666666663,6.9333333333333336,7,7.0666666666666664,7.1333333333333337,7.2000000000000002,7.2666666666666666,7.333333333333333,7.4000000000000004,7.4666666666666668,7.5333333333333332,7.5999999999999996,7.666666666666667,7.7333333333333334,7.7999999999999998,7.8666666666666663,7.9333333333333336,8,8.0666666666666664,8.1333333333333329,8.1999999999999993,8.2666666666666675,8.3333333333333339,8.4000000000000004,8.4666666666666668,8.5333333333333332,8.5999999999999996,8.6666666666666661,8.7333333333333325,8.8000000000000007,8.8666666666666671,8.9333333333333336,9,9.0666666666666664,9.1333333333333329,9.1999999999999993,9.2666666666666675,9.3333333333333339,9.4000000000000004,9.4666666666666668,9.5333333333333332,9.5999999999999996,9.6666666666666661,9.7333333333333325,9.8000000000000007,9.8666666666666671,9.9333333333333336,10,10.066666666666666,10.133333333333333,10.199999999999999,10.266666666666667,10.333333333333334,10.4,10.466666666666667,10.533333333333333,10.6,10.666666666666666,10.733333333333333,10.800000000000001,10.866666666666667,10.933333333333334,11,11.066666666666666,11.133333333333333,11.199999999999999,11.266666666666667,11.333333333333334,11.4,11.466666666666667,11.533333333333333,11.6,11.666666666666666,11.733333333333333,11.800000000000001,11.866666666666667,11.933333333333334,12,12.066666666666666,12.133333333333333,12.199999999999999,12.266666666666667,12.333333333333334,12.4,12.466666666666667,12.533333333333333,12.6,12.666666666666666,12.733333333333333,12.800000000000001,12.866666666666667,12.933333333333334,13,13.066666666666666,13.133333333333333,13.199999999999999,13.266666666666667,13.333333333333334,13.4,13.466666666666667,13.533333333333333,13.6,13.666666666666666,13.733333333333333,13.800000000000001,13.866666666666667,13.933333333333334,14,14.066666666666666,14.133333333333333,14.199999999999999,14.266666666666667,14.333333333333334,14.4,14.466666666666667,14.533333333333333,14.6,14.666666666666666,14.733333333333333,14.800000000000001,14.866666666666667,14.933333333333334,15,15.066666666666666,15.133333333333333,15.199999999999999,15.266666666666667,15.333333333333334,15.4,15.466666666666667,15.533333333333333,15.6,15.666666666666666,15.733333333333333,15.800000000000001,15.866666666666667,15.933333333333334,16,16.066666666666666,16.133333333333333,16.199999999999999,16.266666666666666,16.333333333333332,16.399999999999999,16.466666666666665,16.533333333333335,16.600000000000001,16.666666666666668,16.733333333333334,16.800000000000001,16.866666666666667,16.933333333333334,17,17.066666666666666,17.133333333333333,17.199999999999999,17.266666666666666,17.333333333333332,17.399999999999999,17.466666666666665,17.533333333333335,17.600000000000001,17.666666666666668,17.733333333333334,17.800000000000001,17.866666666666667,17.933333333333334,18,18.066666666666666,18.133333333333333,18.199999999999999,18.266666666666666,18.333333333333332,18.399999999999999,18.466666666666665,18.533333333333335,18.600000000000001,18.666666666666668,18.733333333333334,18.800000000000001,18.866666666666667,18.933333333333334,19,19.066666666666666,19.133333333333333,19.199999999999999,19.266666666666666,19.333333333333332,19.399999999999999,19.466666666666665,19.533333333333335,19.600000000000001,19.666666666666668,19.733333333333334,19.800000000000001,19.866666666666667,19.933333333333334,20,20.066666666666666,20.133333333333333,20.199999999999999,20.266666666666666,20.333333333333332,20.399999999999999,20.466666666666665,20.533333333333335,20.600000000000001,20.666666666666668,20.733333333333334,20.800000000000001,20.866666666666667,20.933333333333334,21,21.066666666666666,21.133333333333333,21.199999999999999,21.266666666666666,21.333333333333332,21.399999999999999,21.466666666666665,21.533333333333335,21.600000000000001,21.666666666666668,21.733333333333334,21.800000000000001,21.866666666666667,21.933333333333334,22,22.066666666666666,22.133333333333333,22.199999999999999,22.266666666666666,22.333333333333332,22.399999999999999,22.466666666666665,22.533333333333335,22.600000000000001,22.666666666666668,22.733333333333334,22.800000000000001,22.866666666666667,22.933333333333334,23,23.066666666666666,23.133333333333333,23.199999999999999,23.266666666666666,23.333333333333332,23.399999999999999,23.466666666666665,23.533333333333335,23.600000000000001,23.666666666666668,23.733333333333334,23.800000000000001,23.866666666666667,23.933333333333334,24,24.066666666666666,24.133333333333333,24.199999999999999,24.266666666666666,24.333333333333332,24.399999999999999,24.466666666666665,24.533333333333335,24.600000000000001,24.666666666666668,24.733333333333334,24.800000000000001,24.866666666666667,24.933333333333334,25,25.066666666666666,25.133333333333333,25.199999999999999,25.266666666666666,25.333333333333332,25.399999999999999,25.466666666666665,25.533333333333335,25.600000000000001,25.666666666666668,25.733333333333334,25.800000000000001,25.866666666666667,25.933333333333334,26,26.066666666666666,26.133333333333333,26.199999999999999,26.266666666666666,26.333333333333332,26.399999999999999,26.466666666666665,26.533333333333335,26.600000000000001,26.666666666666668,26.733333333333334,26.800000000000001,26.866666666666667,26.933333333333334,27,27.066666666666666,27.133333333333333,27.199999999999999,27.266666666666666,27.333333333333332,27.399999999999999,27.466666666666665,27.533333333333335,27.600000000000001,27.666666666666668,27.733333333333334,27.800000000000001,27.866666666666667,27.933333333333334,28,28.066666666666666,28.133333333333333,28.199999999999999,28.266666666666666,28.333333333333332,28.399999999999999,28.466666666666665,28.533333333333335,28.600000000000001,28.666666666666668,28.733333333333334,28.800000000000001,28.866666666666667,28.933333333333334,29,29.066666666666666,29.133333333333333,29.199999999999999,29.266666666666666,29.333333333333332,29.399999999999999,29.466666666666665,29.533333333333335,29.600000000000001,29.666666666666668,29.733333333333334,29.800000000000001,29.866666666666667,29.933333333333334,30,30.066666666666666,30.133333333333333,30.199999999999999,30.266666666666666,30.333333333333332,30.399999999999999,30.466666666666665,30.533333333333335,30.600000000000001,30.666666666666668,30.733333333333334,30.800000000000001,30.866666666666667,30.933333333333334,31,31.066666666666666,31.133333333333333,31.199999999999999,31.266666666666666,31.333333333333332,31.399999999999999,31.466666666666665,31.533333333333335,31.600000000000001,31.666666666666668,31.733333333333334,31.800000000000001,31.866666666666667,31.933333333333334,32,32.06666666666667,32.133333333333333,32.200000000000003,32.266666666666666,32.333333333333336,32.399999999999999,32.466666666666669,32.533333333333331,32.600000000000001,32.666666666666664,32.733333333333334,32.799999999999997,32.866666666666667,32.93333333333333,33,33.06666666666667,33.133333333333333,33.200000000000003,33.266666666666666,33.333333333333336,33.399999999999999,33.466666666666669,33.533333333333331,33.600000000000001,33.666666666666664,33.733333333333334,33.799999999999997,33.866666666666667,33.93333333333333,34,34.06666666666667,34.133333333333333,34.200000000000003,34.266666666666666,34.333333333333336,34.399999999999999,34.466666666666669,34.533333333333331,34.600000000000001,34.666666666666664,34.733333333333334,34.799999999999997,34.866666666666667,34.93333333333333,35,35.06666666666667,35.133333333333333,35.200000000000003,35.266666666666666,35.333333333333336,35.399999999999999,35.466666666666669,35.533333333333331,35.600000000000001,35.666666666666664,35.733333333333334,35.799999999999997,35.866666666666667,35.93333333333333,36,36.06666666666667,36.133333333333333,36.200000000000003,36.266666666666666,36.333333333333336,36.399999999999999,36.466666666666669,36.533333333333331,36.600000000000001,36.666666666666664,36.733333333333334,36.799999999999997,36.866666666666667,36.93333333333333,37,37.06666666666667,37.133333333333333,37.200000000000003,37.266666666666666,37.333333333333336,37.399999999999999,37.466666666666669,37.533333333333331,37.600000000000001,37.666666666666664,37.733333333333334,37.799999999999997,37.866666666666667,37.93333333333333,38,38.06666666666667,38.133333333333333,38.200000000000003,38.266666666666666,38.333333333333336,38.399999999999999,38.466666666666669,38.533333333333331,38.600000000000001,38.666666666666664,38.733333333333334,38.799999999999997,38.866666666666667,38.93333333333333,39,39.06666666666667,39.133333333333333,39.200000000000003,39.266666666666666,39.333333333333336,39.399999999999999,39.466666666666669,39.533333333333331,39.600000000000001,39.666666666666664,39.733333333333334,39.799999999999997,39.866666666666667,39.93333333333333,40,40.06666666666667,40.133333333333333,40.200000000000003,40.266666666666666,40.333333333333336,40.399999999999999,40.466666666666669,40.533333333333331,40.600000000000001,40.666666666666664,40.733333333333334,40.799999999999997,40.866666666666667,40.93333333333333,41,41.06666666666667,41.133333333333333,41.200000000000003,41.266666666666666,41.333333333333336,41.399999999999999,41.466666666666669,41.533333333333331,41.600000000000001,41.666666666666664,41.733333333333334,41.799999999999997,41.866666666666667,41.93333333333333,42,42.06666666666667,42.133333333333333,42.200000000000003,42.266666666666666,42.333333333333336,42.399999999999999,42.466666666666669,42.533333333333331,42.600000000000001,42.666666666666664,42.733333333333334,42.799999999999997,42.866666666666667,42.93333333333333,43,43.06666666666667,43.133333333333333,43.200000000000003,43.266666666666666,43.333333333333336,43.399999999999999,43.466666666666669,43.533333333333331,43.600000000000001,43.666666666666664,43.733333333333334,43.799999999999997,43.866666666666667,43.93333333333333,44,44.06666666666667,44.133333333333333,44.200000000000003,44.266666666666666,44.333333333333336,44.399999999999999,44.466666666666669,44.533333333333331,44.600000000000001,44.666666666666664,44.733333333333334,44.799999999999997,44.866666666666667,44.93333333333333,45,45.06666666666667,45.133333333333333,45.200000000000003,45.266666666666666,45.333333333333336,45.399999999999999,45.466666666666669,45.533333333333331,45.600000000000001,45.666666666666664,45.733333333333334,45.799999999999997,45.866666666666667,45.93333333333333,46,46.06666666666667,46.133333333333333,46.200000000000003,46.266666666666666,46.333333333333336,46.399999999999999,46.466666666666669,46.533333333333331,46.600000000000001,46.666666666666664,46.733333333333334,46.799999999999997,46.866666666666667,46.93333333333333,47,47.06666666666667,47.133333333333333,47.200000000000003,47.266666666666666,47.333333333333336,47.399999999999999,47.466666666666669,47.533333333333331,47.600000000000001,47.666666666666664,47.733333333333334,47.799999999999997,47.866666666666667,47.93333333333333,48,48.06666666666667,48.133333333333333,48.200000000000003,48.266666666666666,48.333333333333336,48.399999999999999,48.466666666666669,48.533333333333331,48.600000000000001,48.666666666666664,48.733333333333334,48.799999999999997,48.866666666666667,48.93333333333333,49,49.06666666666667,49.133333333333333,49.200000000000003,49.266666666666666,49.333333333333336,49.399999999999999,49.466666666666669,49.533333333333331,49.600000000000001,49.666666666666664,49.733333333333334,49.799999999999997,49.866666666666667,49.93333333333333,50,50.06666666666667,50.133333333333333,50.200000000000003,50.266666666666666,50.333333333333336,50.399999999999999,50.466666666666669,50.533333333333331,50.600000000000001,50.666666666666664,50.733333333333334,50.799999999999997,50.866666666666667,50.93333333333333,51,51.06666666666667,51.133333333333333,51.200000000000003,51.266666666666666,51.333333333333336,51.399999999999999,51.466666666666669,51.533333333333331,51.600000000000001,51.666666666666664,51.733333333333334,51.799999999999997,51.866666666666667,51.93333333333333,52,52.06666666666667,52.133333333333333,52.200000000000003,52.266666666666666,52.333333333333336,52.399999999999999,52.466666666666669,52.533333333333331,52.600000000000001,52.666666666666664,52.733333333333334,52.799999999999997,52.866666666666667,52.93333333333333,53,53.06666666666667,53.133333333333333,53.200000000000003,53.266666666666666,53.333333333333336,53.399999999999999,53.466666666666669,53.533333333333331,53.600000000000001,53.666666666666664,53.733333333333334,53.799999999999997,53.866666666666667,53.93333333333333,54,54.06666666666667,54.133333333333333,54.200000000000003,54.266666666666666,54.333333333333336,54.399999999999999,54.466666666666669,54.533333333333331,54.600000000000001,54.666666666666664,54.733333333333334,54.799999999999997,54.866666666666667,54.93333333333333,55,55.06666666666667,55.133333333333333,55.200000000000003,55.266666666666666,55.333333333333336,55.399999999999999,55.466666666666669,55.533333333333331,55.600000000000001,55.666666666666664,55.733333333333334,55.799999999999997,55.866666666666667,55.93333333333333,56,56.06666666666667,56.133333333333333,56.200000000000003,56.266666666666666,56.333333333333336,56.399999999999999,56.466666666666669,56.533333333333331,56.600000000000001,56.666666666666664,56.733333333333334,56.799999999999997,56.866666666666667,56.93333333333333,57,57.06666666666667,57.133333333333333,57.200000000000003,57.266666666666666,57.333333333333336,57.399999999999999,57.466666666666669,57.533333333333331,57.600000000000001,57.666666666666664,57.733333333333334,57.799999999999997,57.866666666666667,57.93333333333333,58,58.06666666666667,58.133333333333333,58.200000000000003,58.266666666666666,58.333333333333336,58.399999999999999,58.466666666666669,58.533333333333331,58.600000000000001,58.666666666666664,58.733333333333334,58.799999999999997,58.866666666666667,58.93333333333333,59,59.06666666666667,59.133333333333333,59.200000000000003,59.266666666666666,59.333333333333336,59.399999999999999,59.466666666666669,59.533333333333331,59.600000000000001,59.666666666666664,59.733333333333334,59.799999999999997,59.866666666666667,59.93333333333333,60,60.06666666666667,60.133333333333333,60.200000000000003,60.266666666666666,60.333333333333336,60.399999999999999,60.466666666666669,60.533333333333331,60.600000000000001,60.666666666666664,60.733333333333334,60.799999999999997,60.866666666666667,60.93333333333333,61,61.06666666666667,61.133333333333333,61.200000000000003,61.266666666666666,61.333333333333336,61.399999999999999,61.466666666666669,61.533333333333331,61.600000000000001,61.666666666666664,61.733333333333334,61.799999999999997,61.866666666666667,61.93333333333333,62,62.06666666666667,62.133333333333333,62.200000000000003,62.266666666666666,62.333333333333336,62.399999999999999,62.466666666666669,62.533333333333331,62.600000000000001,62.666666666666664,62.733333333333334,62.799999999999997,62.866666666666667,62.93333333333333,63,63.06666666666667,63.133333333333333,63.200000000000003,63.266666666666666,63.333333333333336,63.399999999999999,63.466666666666669,63.533333333333331,63.600000000000001,63.666666666666664,63.733333333333334,63.799999999999997,63.866666666666667,63.93333333333333,64,64.066666666666663,64.13333333333334,64.200000000000003,64.266666666666666,64.333333333333329,64.400000000000006,64.466666666666669,64.533333333333331,64.599999999999994,64.666666666666671,64.733333333333334,64.799999999999997,64.86666666666666,64.933333333333337,65,65.066666666666663,65.13333333333334,65.200000000000003,65.266666666666666,65.333333333333329,65.400000000000006,65.466666666666669,65.533333333333331,65.599999999999994,65.666666666666671,65.733333333333334,65.799999999999997,65.86666666666666,65.933333333333337,66,66.066666666666663,66.13333333333334,66.200000000000003,66.266666666666666,66.333333333333329,66.400000000000006,66.466666666666669,66.533333333333331,66.599999999999994,66.666666666666671,66.733333333333334,66.799999999999997,66.86666666666666,66.933333333333337,67,67.066666666666663,67.13333333333334,67.200000000000003,67.266666666666666,67.333333333333329,67.400000000000006,67.466666666666669,67.533333333333331,67.599999999999994,67.666666666666671,67.733333333333334,67.799999999999997,67.86666666666666,67.933333333333337,68,68.066666666666663,68.13333333333334,68.200000000000003,68.266666666666666,68.333333333333329,68.400000000000006,68.466666666666669,68.533333333333331,68.599999999999994,68.666666666666671,68.733333333333334,68.799999999999997,68.86666666666666,68.933333333333337,69,69.066666666666663,69.13333333333334,69.200000000000003,69.266666666666666,69.333333333333329,69.400000000000006,69.466666666666669,69.533333333333331,69.599999999999994,69.666666666666671,69.733333333333334,69.799999999999997,69.86666666666666,69.933333333333337,70,70.066666666666663,70.13333333333334,70.200000000000003,70.266666666666666,70.333333333333329,70.400000000000006,70.466666666666669,70.533333333333331,70.599999999999994,70.666666666666671,70.733333333333334,70.799999999999997,70.86666666666666,70.933333333333337,71,71.066666666666663,71.13333333333334,71.200000000000003,71.266666666666666,71.333333333333329,71.400000000000006,71.466666666666669,71.533333333333331,71.599999999999994,71.666666666666671,71.733333333333334,71.799999999999997,71.86666666666666,71.933333333333337,72,72.066666666666663,72.13333333333334,72.200000000000003,72.266666666666666,72.333333333333329,72.400000000000006,72.466666666666669,72.533333333333331,72.599999999999994,72.666666666666671,72.733333333333334,72.799999999999997,72.86666666666666,72.933333333333337,73,73.066666666666663,73.13333333333334,73.200000000000003,73.266666666666666,73.333333333333329,73.400000000000006,73.466666666666669,73.533333333333331,73.599999999999994,73.666666666666671,73.733333333333334,73.799999999999997,73.86666666666666,73.933333333333337,74,74.066666666666663,74.13333333333334,74.200000000000003,74.266666666666666,74.333333333333329,74.400000000000006,74.466666666666669,74.533333333333331,74.599999999999994,74.666666666666671,74.733333333333334,74.799999999999997,74.86666666666666,74.933333333333337,75,75.066666666666663,75.13333333333334,75.200000000000003,75.266666666666666,75.333333333333329,75.400000000000006,75.466666666666669,75.533333333333331,75.599999999999994,75.666666666666671,75.733333333333334,75.799999999999997,75.86666666666666,75.933333333333337,76,76.066666666666663,76.13333333333334,76.200000000000003,76.266666666666666,76.333333333333329,76.400000000000006,76.466666666666669,76.533333333333331,76.599999999999994,76.666666666666671,76.733333333333334,76.799999999999997,76.86666666666666,76.933333333333337,77,77.066666666666663,77.13333333333334,77.200000000000003,77.266666666666666,77.333333333333329,77.400000000000006,77.466666666666669,77.533333333333331,77.599999999999994,77.666666666666671,77.733333333333334,77.799999999999997,77.86666666666666,77.933333333333337,78,78.066666666666663,78.13333333333334,78.200000000000003,78.266666666666666,78.333333333333329,78.400000000000006,78.466666666666669,78.533333333333331,78.599999999999994,78.666666666666671,78.733333333333334,78.799999999999997,78.86666666666666,78.933333333333337,79,79.066666666666663,79.13333333333334,79.200000000000003,79.266666666666666,79.333333333333329,79.400000000000006,79.466666666666669,79.533333333333331,79.599999999999994,79.666666666666671,79.733333333333334,79.799999999999997,79.86666666666666,79.933333333333337,80,80.066666666666663,80.13333333333334,80.200000000000003,80.266666666666666,80.333333333333329,80.400000000000006,80.466666666666669,80.533333333333331,80.599999999999994,80.666666666666671,80.733333333333334,80.799999999999997,80.86666666666666,80.933333333333337,81,81.066666666666663,81.13333333333334,81.200000000000003,81.266666666666666,81.333333333333329,81.400000000000006,81.466666666666669,81.533333333333331,81.599999999999994,81.666666666666671,81.733333333333334,81.799999999999997,81.86666666666666,81.933333333333337,82,82.066666666666663,82.13333333333334,82.200000000000003,82.266666666666666,82.333333333333329,82.400000000000006,82.466666666666669,82.533333333333331,82.599999999999994,82.666666666666671,82.733333333333334,82.799999999999997,82.86666666666666,82.933333333333337,83,83.066666666666663,83.13333333333334,83.200000000000003,83.266666666666666,83.333333333333329,83.400000000000006,83.466666666666669,83.533333333333331,83.599999999999994,83.666666666666671,83.733333333333334,83.799999999999997,83.86666666666666,83.933333333333337,84,84.066666666666663,84.13333333333334,84.200000000000003,84.266666666666666,84.333333333333329,84.400000000000006,84.466666666666669,84.533333333333331,84.599999999999994,84.666666666666671,84.733333333333334,84.799999999999997,84.86666666666666,84.933333333333337,85,85.066666666666663,85.13333333333334,85.200000000000003,85.266666666666666,85.333333333333329,85.400000000000006,85.466666666666669,85.533333333333331,85.599999999999994,85.666666666666671,85.733333333333334,85.799999999999997,85.86666666666666,85.933333333333337,86,86.066666666666663,86.13333333333334,86.200000000000003,86.266666666666666,86.333333333333329,86.400000000000006,86.466666666666669,86.533333333333331,86.599999999999994,86.666666666666671,86.733333333333334,86.799999999999997,86.86666666666666,86.933333333333337,87,87.066666666666663,87.13333333333334,87.200000000000003,87.266666666666666,87.333333333333329,87.400000000000006,87.466666666666669,87.533333333333331,87.599999999999994,87.666666666666671,87.733333333333334,87.799999999999997,87.86666666666666,87.933333333333337,88,88.066666666666663,88.13333333333334,88.200000000000003,88.266666666666666,88.333333333333329,88.400000000000006,88.466666666666669,88.533333333333331,88.599999999999994,88.666666666666671,88.733333333333334,88.799999999999997,88.86666666666666,88.933333333333337,89,89.066666666666663,89.13333333333334,89.200000000000003,89.266666666666666,89.333333333333329,89.400000000000006,89.466666666666669,89.533333333333331,89.599999999999994,89.666666666666671,89.733333333333334,89.799999999999997,89.86666666666666,89.933333333333337,90,90.066666666666663,90.13333333333334,90.200000000000003,90.266666666666666,90.333333333333329,90.400000000000006,90.466666666666669,90.533333333333331,90.599999999999994,90.666666666666671,90.733333333333334,90.799999999999997,90.86666666666666,90.933333333333337,91,91.066666666666663,91.13333333333334,91.200000000000003,91.266666666666666,91.333333333333329,91.400000000000006,91.466666666666669,91.533333333333331,91.599999999999994,91.666666666666671,91.733333333333334,91.799999999999997,91.86666666666666,91.933333333333337,92,92.066666666666663,92.13333333333334,92.200000000000003,92.266666666666666,92.333333333333329,92.400000000000006,92.466666666666669,92.533333333333331,92.599999999999994,92.666666666666671,92.733333333333334,92.799999999999997,92.86666666666666,92.933333333333337,93,93.066666666666663,93.13333333333334,93.200000000000003,93.266666666666666,93.333333333333329,93.400000000000006,93.466666666666669,93.533333333333331,93.599999999999994,93.666666666666671,93.733333333333334,93.799999999999997,93.86666666666666,93.933333333333337,94,94.066666666666663,94.13333333333334,94.200000000000003,94.266666666666666,94.333333333333329,94.400000000000006,94.466666666666669,94.533333333333331,94.599999999999994,94.666666666666671,94.733333333333334,94.799999999999997,94.86666666666666,94.933333333333337,95,95.066666666666663,95.13333333333334,95.200000000000003,95.266666666666666,95.333333333333329,95.400000000000006,95.466666666666669,95.533333333333331,95.599999999999994,95.666666666666671,95.733333333333334,95.799999999999997,95.86666666666666,95.933333333333337,96,96.066666666666663,96.13333333333334,96.200000000000003,96.266666666666666,96.333333333333329,96.400000000000006,96.466666666666669,96.533333333333331,96.599999999999994,96.666666666666671,96.733333333333334,96.799999999999997,96.86666666666666,96.933333333333337,97,97.066666666666663,97.13333333333334,97.200000000000003,97.266666666666666,97.333333333333329,97.400000000000006,97.466666666666669,97.533333333333331,97.599999999999994,97.666666666666671,97.733333333333334,97.799999999999997,97.86666666666666,97.933333333333337,98,98.066666666666663,98.13333333333334,98.200000000000003,98.266666666666666,98.333333333333329,98.400000000000006,98.466666666666669,98.533333333333331,98.599999999999994,98.666666666666671,98.733333333333334,98.799999999999997,98.86666666666666,98.933333333333337,99,99.066666666666663,99.13333333333334,99.200000000000003,99.266666666666666,99.333333333333329,99.400000000000006,99.466666666666669,99.533333333333331,99.599999999999994,99.666666666666671,99.733333333333334,99.799999999999997,99.86666666666666,99.933333333333337,100,100.06666666666666,100.13333333333334,100.2,100.26666666666667,100.33333333333333,100.40000000000001,100.46666666666667,100.53333333333333,100.59999999999999,100.66666666666667,100.73333333333333,100.8,100.86666666666666,100.93333333333334]
```

I need to make a key-value pair dictionary grouping as following. (e.g. `[String: [Double]`)

```
{"0":[0,0.066666666666666666,0.13333333333333333,0.20000000000000001,0.26666666666666666,0.33333333333333331,0.40000000000000002,0.46666666666666667,0.53333333333333333,0.59999999999999998,0.66666666666666663,0.73333333333333328,0.80000000000000004,0.8666666666666667,0.93333333333333335],"1":[1,1.0666666666666667,1.1333333333333333,1.2,1.2666666666666666,1.3333333333333333,1.3999999999999999,1.4666666666666666,1.5333333333333334,1.6000000000000001,1.6666666666666667,1.7333333333333334,1.8,1.8666666666666667,1.9333333333333333],"2":[2,2.0666666666666669,2.1333333333333333,2.2000000000000002,2.2666666666666666,2.3333333333333335,2.3999999999999999,2.4666666666666668,2.5333333333333332,2.6000000000000001,2.6666666666666665,2.7333333333333334,2.7999999999999998,2.8666666666666667,2.9333333333333331]}
```

How can I achieve this using Swift programming language?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Dictionary initializer grouping by

```
init<S>(grouping values: S, by keyForValue: (S.Element) throws -> Key) rethrows where Value == [S.Element], S : Sequence
```

and coerce your double to integer and return a string from it:

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: values) { String(Int($0)) }
```

Comment: Excellent solution!

Comment: @RasheshBosamiya Do you know how to mark an answer as correct?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Dictionary(grouping:)`

```
var input = [0,0.066666666666666666,0.13333333333333333,0.20000000000000001,0.26666666666666666,0.33333333333333331,0.40000000000000002,0.46666666666666667,0.53333333333333333,0.59999999999999998,0.66666666666666663,0.73333333333333328,0.80000000000000004,0.8666666666666667,0.93333333333333335,1,1.0666666666666667,1.1333333333333333,1.2,1.2666666666666666,1.3333333333333333,1.3999999999999999,1.4666666666666666,1.5333333333333334,1.6000000000000001,1.6666666666666667,1.7333333333333334,1.8,1.8666666666666667,1.9333333333333333,2,2.0666666666666669,2.1333333333333333,2.2000000000000002,2.2666666666666666,2.3333333333333335,2.3999999999999999,2.4666666666666668,2.5333333333333332,2.6000000000000001,2.6666666666666665,2.7333333333333334,2.7999999999999998,2.8666666666666667,2.9333333333333331,3,3.0666666666666669,3.1333333333333333,3.2000000000000002,3.2666666666666666,3.3333333333333335,3.3999999999999999,3.4666666666666668,3.5333333333333332,3.6000000000000001,3.6666666666666665,3.7333333333333334,3.7999999999999998,3.8666666666666667,3.9333333333333331,4,4.0666666666666664,4.1333333333333337,4.2000000000000002,4.2666666666666666,4.333333333333333,4.4000000000000004,4.4666666666666668,4.5333333333333332,4.5999999999999996,4.666666666666667,4.7333333333333334,4.7999999999999998,4.8666666666666663,4.9333333333333336,5,5.0666666666666664,5.1333333333333337,5.2000000000000002,5.2666666666666666,5.333333333333333,5.4000000000000004,5.4666666666666668,5.5333333333333332,5.5999999999999996,5.666666666666667,5.7333333333333334,5.7999999999999998,5.8666666666666663,5.9333333333333336,6,6.0666666666666664,6.1333333333333337,6.2000000000000002,6.2666666666666666,6.333333333333333,6.4000000000000004,6.4666666666666668,6.5333333333333332,6.5999999999999996,6.666666666666667,6.7333333333333334,6.7999999999999998,6.8666666666666663,6.9333333333333336,7,7.0666666666666664,7.1333333333333337,7.2000000000000002,7.2666666666666666,7.333333333333333,7.4000000000000004,7.4666666666666668,7.5333333333333332,7.5999999999999996,7.666666666666667,7.7333333333333334,7.7999999999999998,7.8666666666666663,7.9333333333333336,8,8.0666666666666664,8.1333333333333329,8.1999999999999993,8.2666666666666675,8.3333333333333339,8.4000000000000004,8.4666666666666668,8.5333333333333332,8.5999999999999996,8.6666666666666661,8.7333333333333325,8.8000000000000007,8.8666666666666671,8.9333333333333336,9,9.0666666666666664,9.1333333333333329,9.1999999999999993,9.2666666666666675,9.3333333333333339,9.4000000000000004,9.4666666666666668,9.5333333333333332,9.5999999999999996,9.6666666666666661,9.7333333333333325,9.8000000000000007,9.8666666666666671,9.9333333333333336,10,10.066666666666666,10.133333333333333,10.199999999999999,10.266666666666667,10.333333333333334,10.4,10.466666666666667,10.533333333333333,10.6,10.666666666666666,10.733333333333333,10.800000000000001,10.866666666666667,10.933333333333334,11,11.066666666666666,11.133333333333333,11.199999999999999,11.266666666666667,11.333333333333334,11.4,11.466666666666667,11.533333333333333,11.6,11.666666666666666,11.733333333333333,11.800000000000001,11.866666666666667,11.933333333333334,12,12.066666666666666,12.133333333333333,12.199999999999999,12.266666666666667,12.333333333333334,12.4,12.466666666666667,12.533333333333333,12.6,12.666666666666666,12.733333333333333,12.800000000000001,12.866666666666667,12.933333333333334,13,13.066666666666666,13.133333333333333,13.199999999999999,13.266666666666667,13.333333333333334,13.4,13.466666666666667,13.533333333333333,13.6,13.666666666666666,13.733333333333333,13.800000000000001,13.866666666666667,13.933333333333334,14,14.066666666666666,14.133333333333333,14.199999999999999,14.266666666666667,14.333333333333334,14.4,14.466666666666667,14.533333333333333,14.6,14.666666666666666,14.733333333333333,14.800000000000001,14.866666666666667,14.933333333333334,15,15.066666666666666,15.133333333333333,15.199999999999999,15.266666666666667,15.333333333333334,15.4,15.466666666666667,15.533333333333333,15.6,15.666666666666666,15.733333333333333,15.800000000000001,15.866666666666667,15.933333333333334,16,16.066666666666666,16.133333333333333,16.199999999999999,16.266666666666666,16.333333333333332,16.399999999999999,16.466666666666665,16.533333333333335,16.600000000000001,16.666666666666668,16.733333333333334,16.800000000000001,16.866666666666667,16.933333333333334,17,17.066666666666666,17.133333333333333,17.199999999999999,17.266666666666666,17.333333333333332,17.399999999999999,17.466666666666665,17.533333333333335,17.600000000000001,17.666666666666668,17.733333333333334,17.800000000000001,17.866666666666667,17.933333333333334,18,18.066666666666666,18.133333333333333,18.199999999999999,18.266666666666666,18.333333333333332,18.399999999999999,18.466666666666665,18.533333333333335,18.600000000000001,18.666666666666668,18.733333333333334,18.800000000000001,18.866666666666667,18.933333333333334,19,19.066666666666666,19.133333333333333,19.199999999999999,19.266666666666666,19.333333333333332,19.399999999999999,19.466666666666665,19.533333333333335,19.600000000000001,19.666666666666668,19.733333333333334,19.800000000000001,19.866666666666667,19.933333333333334,20,20.066666666666666,20.133333333333333,20.199999999999999,20.266666666666666,20.333333333333332,20.399999999999999,20.466666666666665,20.533333333333335,20.600000000000001,20.666666666666668,20.733333333333334,20.800000000000001,20.866666666666667,20.933333333333334,21,21.066666666666666,21.133333333333333,21.199999999999999,21.266666666666666,21.333333333333332,21.399999999999999,21.466666666666665,21.533333333333335,21.600000000000001,21.666666666666668,21.733333333333334,21.800000000000001,21.866666666666667,21.933333333333334,22,22.066666666666666,22.133333333333333,22.199999999999999,22.266666666666666,22.333333333333332,22.399999999999999,22.466666666666665,22.533333333333335,22.600000000000001,22.666666666666668,22.733333333333334,22.800000000000001,22.866666666666667,22.933333333333334,23,23.066666666666666,23.133333333333333,23.199999999999999,23.266666666666666,23.333333333333332,23.399999999999999,23.466666666666665,23.533333333333335,23.600000000000001,23.666666666666668,23.733333333333334,23.800000000000001,23.866666666666667,23.933333333333334,24,24.066666666666666,24.133333333333333,24.199999999999999,24.266666666666666,24.333333333333332,24.399999999999999,24.466666666666665,24.533333333333335,24.600000000000001,24.666666666666668,24.733333333333334,24.800000000000001,24.866666666666667,24.933333333333334,25,25.066666666666666,25.133333333333333,25.199999999999999,25.266666666666666,25.333333333333332,25.399999999999999,25.466666666666665,25.533333333333335,25.600000000000001,25.666666666666668,25.733333333333334,25.800000000000001,25.866666666666667,25.933333333333334,26,26.066666666666666,26.133333333333333,26.199999999999999,26.266666666666666,26.333333333333332,26.399999999999999,26.466666666666665,26.533333333333335,26.600000000000001,26.666666666666668,26.733333333333334,26.800000000000001,26.866666666666667,26.933333333333334,27,27.066666666666666,27.133333333333333,27.199999999999999,27.266666666666666,27.333333333333332,27.399999999999999,27.466666666666665,27.533333333333335,27.600000000000001,27.666666666666668,27.733333333333334,27.800000000000001,27.866666666666667,27.933333333333334,28,28.066666666666666,28.133333333333333,28.199999999999999,28.266666666666666,28.333333333333332,28.399999999999999,28.466666666666665,28.533333333333335,28.600000000000001,28.666666666666668,28.733333333333334,28.800000000000001,28.866666666666667,28.933333333333334,29,29.066666666666666,29.133333333333333,29.199999999999999,29.266666666666666,29.333333333333332,29.399999999999999,29.466666666666665,29.533333333333335,29.600000000000001,29.666666666666668,29.733333333333334,29.800000000000001,29.866666666666667,29.933333333333334,30,30.066666666666666,30.133333333333333,30.199999999999999,30.266666666666666,30.333333333333332,30.399999999999999,30.466666666666665,30.533333333333335,30.600000000000001,30.666666666666668,30.733333333333334,30.800000000000001,30.866666666666667,30.933333333333334,31,31.066666666666666,31.133333333333333,31.199999999999999,31.266666666666666,31.333333333333332,31.399999999999999,31.466666666666665,31.533333333333335,31.600000000000001,31.666666666666668,31.733333333333334,31.800000000000001,31.866666666666667,31.933333333333334,32,32.06666666666667,32.133333333333333,32.200000000000003,32.266666666666666,32.333333333333336,32.399999999999999,32.466666666666669,32.533333333333331,32.600000000000001,32.666666666666664,32.733333333333334,32.799999999999997,32.866666666666667,32.93333333333333,33,33.06666666666667,33.133333333333333,33.200000000000003,33.266666666666666,33.333333333333336,33.399999999999999,33.466666666666669,33.533333333333331,33.600000000000001,33.666666666666664,33.733333333333334,33.799999999999997,33.866666666666667,33.93333333333333,34,34.06666666666667,34.133333333333333,34.200000000000003,34.266666666666666,34.333333333333336,34.399999999999999,34.466666666666669,34.533333333333331,34.600000000000001,34.666666666666664,34.733333333333334,34.799999999999997,34.866666666666667,34.93333333333333,35,35.06666666666667,35.133333333333333,35.200000000000003,35.266666666666666,35.333333333333336,35.399999999999999,35.466666666666669,35.533333333333331,35.600000000000001,35.666666666666664,35.733333333333334,35.799999999999997,35.866666666666667,35.93333333333333,36,36.06666666666667,36.133333333333333,36.200000000000003,36.266666666666666,36.333333333333336,36.399999999999999,36.466666666666669,36.533333333333331,36.600000000000001,36.666666666666664,36.733333333333334,36.799999999999997,36.866666666666667,36.93333333333333,37,37.06666666666667,37.133333333333333,37.200000000000003,37.266666666666666,37.333333333333336,37.399999999999999,37.466666666666669,37.533333333333331,37.600000000000001,37.666666666666664,37.733333333333334,37.799999999999997,37.866666666666667,37.93333333333333,38,38.06666666666667,38.133333333333333,38.200000000000003,38.266666666666666,38.333333333333336,38.399999999999999,38.466666666666669,38.533333333333331,38.600000000000001,38.666666666666664,38.733333333333334,38.799999999999997,38.866666666666667,38.93333333333333,39,39.06666666666667,39.133333333333333,39.200000000000003,39.266666666666666,39.333333333333336,39.399999999999999,39.466666666666669,39.533333333333331,39.600000000000001,39.666666666666664,39.733333333333334,39.799999999999997,39.866666666666667,39.93333333333333,40,40.06666666666667,40.133333333333333,40.200000000000003,40.266666666666666,40.333333333333336,40.399999999999999,40.466666666666669,40.533333333333331,40.600000000000001,40.666666666666664,40.733333333333334,40.799999999999997,40.866666666666667,40.93333333333333,41,41.06666666666667,41.133333333333333,41.200000000000003,41.266666666666666,41.333333333333336,41.399999999999999,41.466666666666669,41.533333333333331,41.600000000000001,41.666666666666664,41.733333333333334,41.799999999999997,41.866666666666667,41.93333333333333,42,42.06666666666667,42.133333333333333,42.200000000000003,42.266666666666666,42.333333333333336,42.399999999999999,42.466666666666669,42.533333333333331,42.600000000000001,42.666666666666664,42.733333333333334,42.799999999999997,42.866666666666667,42.93333333333333,43,43.06666666666667,43.133333333333333,43.200000000000003,43.266666666666666,43.333333333333336,43.399999999999999,43.466666666666669,43.533333333333331,43.600000000000001,43.666666666666664,43.733333333333334,43.799999999999997,43.866666666666667,43.93333333333333,44,44.06666666666667,44.133333333333333,44.200000000000003,44.266666666666666,44.333333333333336,44.399999999999999,44.466666666666669,44.533333333333331,44.600000000000001,44.666666666666664,44.733333333333334,44.799999999999997,44.866666666666667,44.93333333333333,45,45.06666666666667,45.133333333333333,45.200000000000003,45.266666666666666,45.333333333333336,45.399999999999999,45.466666666666669,45.533333333333331,45.600000000000001,45.666666666666664,45.733333333333334,45.799999999999997,45.866666666666667,45.93333333333333,46,46.06666666666667,46.133333333333333,46.200000000000003,46.266666666666666,46.333333333333336,46.399999999999999,46.466666666666669,46.533333333333331,46.600000000000001,46.666666666666664,46.733333333333334,46.799999999999997,46.866666666666667,46.93333333333333,47,47.06666666666667,47.133333333333333,47.200000000000003,47.266666666666666,47.333333333333336,47.399999999999999,47.466666666666669,47.533333333333331,47.600000000000001,47.666666666666664,47.733333333333334,47.799999999999997,47.866666666666667,47.93333333333333,48,48.06666666666667,48.133333333333333,48.200000000000003,48.266666666666666,48.333333333333336,48.399999999999999,48.466666666666669,48.533333333333331,48.600000000000001,48.666666666666664,48.733333333333334,48.799999999999997,48.866666666666667,48.93333333333333,49,49.06666666666667,49.133333333333333,49.200000000000003,49.266666666666666,49.333333333333336,49.399999999999999,49.466666666666669,49.533333333333331,49.600000000000001,49.666666666666664,49.733333333333334,49.799999999999997,49.866666666666667,49.93333333333333,50,50.06666666666667,50.133333333333333,50.200000000000003,50.266666666666666,50.333333333333336,50.399999999999999,50.466666666666669,50.533333333333331,50.600000000000001,50.666666666666664,50.733333333333334,50.799999999999997,50.866666666666667,50.93333333333333,51,51.06666666666667,51.133333333333333,51.200000000000003,51.266666666666666,51.333333333333336,51.399999999999999,51.466666666666669,51.533333333333331,51.600000000000001,51.666666666666664,51.733333333333334,51.799999999999997,51.866666666666667,51.93333333333333,52,52.06666666666667,52.133333333333333,52.200000000000003,52.266666666666666,52.333333333333336,52.399999999999999,52.466666666666669,52.533333333333331,52.600000000000001,52.666666666666664,52.733333333333334,52.799999999999997,52.866666666666667,52.93333333333333,53,53.06666666666667,53.133333333333333,53.200000000000003,53.266666666666666,53.333333333333336,53.399999999999999,53.466666666666669,53.533333333333331,53.600000000000001,53.666666666666664,53.733333333333334,53.799999999999997,53.866666666666667,53.93333333333333,54,54.06666666666667,54.133333333333333,54.200000000000003,54.266666666666666,54.333333333333336,54.399999999999999,54.466666666666669,54.533333333333331,54.600000000000001,54.666666666666664,54.733333333333334,54.799999999999997,54.866666666666667,54.93333333333333,55,55.06666666666667,55.133333333333333,55.200000000000003,55.266666666666666,55.333333333333336,55.399999999999999,55.466666666666669,55.533333333333331,55.600000000000001,55.666666666666664,55.733333333333334,55.799999999999997,55.866666666666667,55.93333333333333,56,56.06666666666667,56.133333333333333,56.200000000000003,56.266666666666666,56.333333333333336,56.399999999999999,56.466666666666669,56.533333333333331,56.600000000000001,56.666666666666664,56.733333333333334,56.799999999999997,56.866666666666667,56.93333333333333,57,57.06666666666667,57.133333333333333,57.200000000000003,57.266666666666666,57.333333333333336,57.399999999999999,57.466666666666669,57.533333333333331,57.600000000000001,57.666666666666664,57.733333333333334,57.799999999999997,57.866666666666667,57.93333333333333,58,58.06666666666667,58.133333333333333,58.200000000000003,58.266666666666666,58.333333333333336,58.399999999999999,58.466666666666669,58.533333333333331,58.600000000000001,58.666666666666664,58.733333333333334,58.799999999999997,58.866666666666667,58.93333333333333,59,59.06666666666667,59.133333333333333,59.200000000000003,59.266666666666666,59.333333333333336,59.399999999999999,59.466666666666669,59.533333333333331,59.600000000000001,59.666666666666664,59.733333333333334,59.799999999999997,59.866666666666667,59.93333333333333,60,60.06666666666667,60.133333333333333,60.200000000000003,60.266666666666666,60.333333333333336,60.399999999999999,60.466666666666669,60.533333333333331,60.600000000000001,60.666666666666664,60.733333333333334,60.799999999999997,60.866666666666667,60.93333333333333,61,61.06666666666667,61.133333333333333,61.200000000000003,61.266666666666666,61.333333333333336,61.399999999999999,61.466666666666669,61.533333333333331,61.600000000000001,61.666666666666664,61.733333333333334,61.799999999999997,61.866666666666667,61.93333333333333,62,62.06666666666667,62.133333333333333,62.200000000000003,62.266666666666666,62.333333333333336,62.399999999999999,62.466666666666669,62.533333333333331,62.600000000000001,62.666666666666664,62.733333333333334,62.799999999999997,62.866666666666667,62.93333333333333,63,63.06666666666667,63.133333333333333,63.200000000000003,63.266666666666666,63.333333333333336,63.399999999999999,63.466666666666669,63.533333333333331,63.600000000000001,63.666666666666664,63.733333333333334,63.799999999999997,63.866666666666667,63.93333333333333,64,64.066666666666663,64.13333333333334,64.200000000000003,64.266666666666666,64.333333333333329,64.400000000000006,64.466666666666669,64.533333333333331,64.599999999999994,64.666666666666671,64.733333333333334,64.799999999999997,64.86666666666666,64.933333333333337,65,65.066666666666663,65.13333333333334,65.200000000000003,65.266666666666666,65.333333333333329,65.400000000000006,65.466666666666669,65.533333333333331,65.599999999999994,65.666666666666671,65.733333333333334,65.799999999999997,65.86666666666666,65.933333333333337,66,66.066666666666663,66.13333333333334,66.200000000000003,66.266666666666666,66.333333333333329,66.400000000000006,66.466666666666669,66.533333333333331,66.599999999999994,66.666666666666671,66.733333333333334,66.799999999999997,66.86666666666666,66.933333333333337,67,67.066666666666663,67.13333333333334,67.200000000000003,67.266666666666666,67.333333333333329,67.400000000000006,67.466666666666669,67.533333333333331,67.599999999999994,67.666666666666671,67.733333333333334,67.799999999999997,67.86666666666666,67.933333333333337,68,68.066666666666663,68.13333333333334,68.200000000000003,68.266666666666666,68.333333333333329,68.400000000000006,68.466666666666669,68.533333333333331,68.599999999999994,68.666666666666671,68.733333333333334,68.799999999999997,68.86666666666666,68.933333333333337,69,69.066666666666663,69.13333333333334,69.200000000000003,69.266666666666666,69.333333333333329,69.400000000000006,69.466666666666669,69.533333333333331,69.599999999999994,69.666666666666671,69.733333333333334,69.799999999999997,69.86666666666666,69.933333333333337,70,70.066666666666663,70.13333333333334,70.200000000000003,70.266666666666666,70.333333333333329,70.400000000000006,70.466666666666669,70.533333333333331,70.599999999999994,70.666666666666671,70.733333333333334,70.799999999999997,70.86666666666666,70.933333333333337,71,71.066666666666663,71.13333333333334,71.200000000000003,71.266666666666666,71.333333333333329,71.400000000000006,71.466666666666669,71.533333333333331,71.599999999999994,71.666666666666671,71.733333333333334,71.799999999999997,71.86666666666666,71.933333333333337,72,72.066666666666663,72.13333333333334,72.200000000000003,72.266666666666666,72.333333333333329,72.400000000000006,72.466666666666669,72.533333333333331,72.599999999999994,72.666666666666671,72.733333333333334,72.799999999999997,72.86666666666666,72.933333333333337,73,73.066666666666663,73.13333333333334,73.200000000000003,73.266666666666666,73.333333333333329,73.400000000000006,73.466666666666669,73.533333333333331,73.599999999999994,73.666666666666671,73.733333333333334,73.799999999999997,73.86666666666666,73.933333333333337,74,74.066666666666663,74.13333333333334,74.200000000000003,74.266666666666666,74.333333333333329,74.400000000000006,74.466666666666669,74.533333333333331,74.599999999999994,74.666666666666671,74.733333333333334,74.799999999999997,74.86666666666666,74.933333333333337,75,75.066666666666663,75.13333333333334,75.200000000000003,75.266666666666666,75.333333333333329,75.400000000000006,75.466666666666669,75.533333333333331,75.599999999999994,75.666666666666671,75.733333333333334,75.799999999999997,75.86666666666666,75.933333333333337,76,76.066666666666663,76.13333333333334,76.200000000000003,76.266666666666666,76.333333333333329,76.400000000000006,76.466666666666669,76.533333333333331,76.599999999999994,76.666666666666671,76.733333333333334,76.799999999999997,76.86666666666666,76.933333333333337,77,77.066666666666663,77.13333333333334,77.200000000000003,77.266666666666666,77.333333333333329,77.400000000000006,77.466666666666669,77.533333333333331,77.599999999999994,77.666666666666671,77.733333333333334,77.799999999999997,77.86666666666666,77.933333333333337,78,78.066666666666663,78.13333333333334,78.200000000000003,78.266666666666666,78.333333333333329,78.400000000000006,78.466666666666669,78.533333333333331,78.599999999999994,78.666666666666671,78.733333333333334,78.799999999999997,78.86666666666666,78.933333333333337,79,79.066666666666663,79.13333333333334,79.200000000000003,79.266666666666666,79.333333333333329,79.400000000000006,79.466666666666669,79.533333333333331,79.599999999999994,79.666666666666671,79.733333333333334,79.799999999999997,79.86666666666666,79.933333333333337,80,80.066666666666663,80.13333333333334,80.200000000000003,80.266666666666666,80.333333333333329,80.400000000000006,80.466666666666669,80.533333333333331,80.599999999999994,80.666666666666671,80.733333333333334,80.799999999999997,80.86666666666666,80.933333333333337,81,81.066666666666663,81.13333333333334,81.200000000000003,81.266666666666666,81.333333333333329,81.400000000000006,81.466666666666669,81.533333333333331,81.599999999999994,81.666666666666671,81.733333333333334,81.799999999999997,81.86666666666666,81.933333333333337,82,82.066666666666663,82.13333333333334,82.200000000000003,82.266666666666666,82.333333333333329,82.400000000000006,82.466666666666669,82.533333333333331,82.599999999999994,82.666666666666671,82.733333333333334,82.799999999999997,82.86666666666666,82.933333333333337,83,83.066666666666663,83.13333333333334,83.200000000000003,83.266666666666666,83.333333333333329,83.400000000000006,83.466666666666669,83.533333333333331,83.599999999999994,83.666666666666671,83.733333333333334,83.799999999999997,83.86666666666666,83.933333333333337,84,84.066666666666663,84.13333333333334,84.200000000000003,84.266666666666666,84.333333333333329,84.400000000000006,84.466666666666669,84.533333333333331,84.599999999999994,84.666666666666671,84.733333333333334,84.799999999999997,84.86666666666666,84.933333333333337,85,85.066666666666663,85.13333333333334,85.200000000000003,85.266666666666666,85.333333333333329,85.400000000000006,85.466666666666669,85.533333333333331,85.599999999999994,85.666666666666671,85.733333333333334,85.799999999999997,85.86666666666666,85.933333333333337,86,86.066666666666663,86.13333333333334,86.200000000000003,86.266666666666666,86.333333333333329,86.400000000000006,86.466666666666669,86.533333333333331,86.599999999999994,86.666666666666671,86.733333333333334,86.799999999999997,86.86666666666666,86.933333333333337,87,87.066666666666663,87.13333333333334,87.200000000000003,87.266666666666666,87.333333333333329,87.400000000000006,87.466666666666669,87.533333333333331,87.599999999999994,87.666666666666671,87.733333333333334,87.799999999999997,87.86666666666666,87.933333333333337,88,88.066666666666663,88.13333333333334,88.200000000000003,88.266666666666666,88.333333333333329,88.400000000000006,88.466666666666669,88.533333333333331,88.599999999999994,88.666666666666671,88.733333333333334,88.799999999999997,88.86666666666666,88.933333333333337,89,89.066666666666663,89.13333333333334,89.200000000000003,89.266666666666666,89.333333333333329,89.400000000000006,89.466666666666669,89.533333333333331,89.599999999999994,89.666666666666671,89.733333333333334,89.799999999999997,89.86666666666666,89.933333333333337,90,90.066666666666663,90.13333333333334,90.200000000000003,90.266666666666666,90.333333333333329,90.400000000000006,90.466666666666669,90.533333333333331,90.599999999999994,90.666666666666671,90.733333333333334,90.799999999999997,90.86666666666666,90.933333333333337,91,91.066666666666663,91.13333333333334,91.200000000000003,91.266666666666666,91.333333333333329,91.400000000000006,91.466666666666669,91.533333333333331,91.599999999999994,91.666666666666671,91.733333333333334,91.799999999999997,91.86666666666666,91.933333333333337,92,92.066666666666663,92.13333333333334,92.200000000000003,92.266666666666666,92.333333333333329,92.400000000000006,92.466666666666669,92.533333333333331,92.599999999999994,92.666666666666671,92.733333333333334,92.799999999999997,92.86666666666666,92.933333333333337,93,93.066666666666663,93.13333333333334,93.200000000000003,93.266666666666666,93.333333333333329,93.400000000000006,93.466666666666669,93.533333333333331,93.599999999999994,93.666666666666671,93.733333333333334,93.799999999999997,93.86666666666666,93.933333333333337,94,94.066666666666663,94.13333333333334,94.200000000000003,94.266666666666666,94.333333333333329,94.400000000000006,94.466666666666669,94.533333333333331,94.599999999999994,94.666666666666671,94.733333333333334,94.799999999999997,94.86666666666666,94.933333333333337,95,95.066666666666663,95.13333333333334,95.200000000000003,95.266666666666666,95.333333333333329,95.400000000000006,95.466666666666669,95.533333333333331,95.599999999999994,95.666666666666671,95.733333333333334,95.799999999999997,95.86666666666666,95.933333333333337,96,96.066666666666663,96.13333333333334,96.200000000000003,96.266666666666666,96.333333333333329,96.400000000000006,96.466666666666669,96.533333333333331,96.599999999999994,96.666666666666671,96.733333333333334,96.799999999999997,96.86666666666666,96.933333333333337,97,97.066666666666663,97.13333333333334,97.200000000000003,97.266666666666666,97.333333333333329,97.400000000000006,97.466666666666669,97.533333333333331,97.599999999999994,97.666666666666671,97.733333333333334,97.799999999999997,97.86666666666666,97.933333333333337,98,98.066666666666663,98.13333333333334,98.200000000000003,98.266666666666666,98.333333333333329,98.400000000000006,98.466666666666669,98.533333333333331,98.599999999999994,98.666666666666671,98.733333333333334,98.799999999999997,98.86666666666666,98.933333333333337,99,99.066666666666663,99.13333333333334,99.200000000000003,99.266666666666666,99.333333333333329,99.400000000000006,99.466666666666669,99.533333333333331,99.599999999999994,99.666666666666671,99.733333333333334,99.799999999999997,99.86666666666666,99.933333333333337,100,100.06666666666666,100.13333333333334,100.2,100.26666666666667,100.33333333333333,100.40000000000001,100.46666666666667,100.53333333333333,100.59999999999999,100.66666666666667,100.73333333333333,100.8,100.86666666666666,100.93333333333334]

var output = Dictionary(grouping: input){ Int($0) }.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0}) // Sorting is optional
print(output)
```

Comment: You can clean it up a little bit more: `Dictionary(grouping: input) { Int($0) }.sorted { $0 < $1 }`

Comment: @EmilioPelaez No. You can't sort key value pairs. What you need is to sort its keys `Dictionary(grouping: input, by: Int.init).sorted(by: {$0.key < $1.key})`. Note that OP wants the keys to be a String. So this is not exactly what he wants

Comment: OP wants a Dictionary: `[String : [Double]]`.  You are producing `[(key: Int, value: [Double])]` which is an array of tuples.

Comment: Nearly this is what I was looking for. Thanks Raja Kishan
Thanks other commenters as well for reshaping answer.

Comment: I was correcting style, not functionality. I did notice that it wouldn’t make sense to run sorted in a dict, but got distracted and didn’t add that comment.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I added sorted for checking output. It's optional